# Pass variable to systemProperty in gradle

Tags: gradle

My gradle file looks like this:

```
test {
    systemProperty 'my.example.timeout.millis', '2500'
}

run {
    systemProperty 'my.example.timeout.millis', '1500'
}
```

But I would like to do something like:

```
timeOut = 'my.example.timeout.millis' 

test {
    systemProperty timeOut, '2500'
}

run {
    println timeOut        //prints expected value
    systemProperty timeOut, '1500'
}
```

For some reason I can't get the `systemProperty` set this way. The `println` works though. How come?

What is the best way to define this `systemProperty` only once and still being able to use it in both the test - and the run task?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
project.ext.timeOut ='my.example.timeout.millis' 

test {
    systemProperty timeOut, '2500'
}

run {
    println timeOut        //prints expected value
    systemProperty timeOut, '1500'
}
```

Properties in script should be defined via `ext` field of `project` instance.

Comment: Great... that did it! Thanks a lot. I tried earlier with just 'ext.timeOut' (defined in other common.gradle script) but that didn't work though.

Comment: You're welcome. If it helped, please accept the answer.